# Audio Framing of 100 ms in java.

Tags: java, audio, frame

I want to get the audio frames of 100 ms from audio file. i use the below code to get frames but i only get data in few starting frames .i am not much aware of audio file processing in java .please help me and guide me. i am right or some thing is wrong. sorry for my bad English.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException {
    byte[] audioBytes;
    File file = new File("3.wav");
    AudioInputStream frame;
    AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
    AudioFileFormat fileFormat = AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(file);
    AudioFormat format = fileFormat.getFormat();
    long audioFileLength = file.length();
    int frameSize = format.getFrameSize();
    double frameRate =  format.getFrameRate();
    int frameDuration = 10;
    double frameLength =   (  (frameRate * frameSize) / frameDuration );
    double numOfFrames =  (audioFileLength /frameLength);
    long remaining = audioFileLength;
    long framesOfAudioToCopy =  (long) ( format.getFrameRate() / frameDuration );
    System.out.println(framesOfAudioToCopy);
    int i = 0;
    while(remaining > frameLength  )
    {
        audioInputStream.skip((long) (i * frameLength));
        frame = new AudioInputStream(audioInputStream, format,  framesOfAudioToCopy );
        audioBytes = new byte[frame.available()];
        frame.read(audioBytes);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(audioBytes)); 
        i++;
        remaining  =  (long) (remaining - frameLength);
      /*  if(remaining < frameLength)
        {
            i++;
            audioInputStream.skip((long) (i * frameLength));            
            frame = new AudioInputStream(audioInputStream, format,  framesOfAudioToCopy );          
            audioBytes = new byte[frame.available()];
            frame.read(audioBytes);                
        }*/
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're doing a lot of extra stuff that you don't need to. Here is a much simpler rewrite which does what (I think) you're describing:

```
int numBytesIn100Millis =
    ((int) (format.getFrameRate() / 10)) * format.getFrameSize();
byte[] buffer = new byte[numBytesIn100Millis];

for (;;) {
    int bytesRead = audioInputStream.read(buffer);
    if (bytesRead < 0)
        break;
    if (bytesRead < buffer.length)
        // this just fills the end of 'buffer' with 0s
        // if read() didn't fill the entire array
        Arrays.fill(buffer, bytesRead, buffer.length, ((byte) 0));

    // 'buffer' now has 100ms of audio
}
```

The problems you're having are probably due to how you're using `skip` and creating a new `AudioInputStream` every time you read:

```
audioInputStream.skip((long) (i * frameLength));
frame = new AudioInputStream(audioInputStream, format,  framesOfAudioToCopy );
```

Reading from `frame` causes `audioInputStream` to get advanced as well.

I don't see a reason to do things that way, anyway. It's complicated and unnecessary.

Comment: thnaks for your reply. it is amazing and work perfect. once again thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. If you think this solves the problem, you can consider accepting my answer. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers